# Aid to North Korea

Tags: north-korea, foreign-aid

Does any country other than China publicly provide aid and grants in any form to North Korea? If so, how much and for what?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This **[article](http://fas.org/sgp/crs/row/R40095.pdf)** , provides substantial information about the foreign aid given to North Korea. In general, North Korea has adeptly managed to shore up aid since the mid 1990s by turning to different countries at different moments. Aid from countries comes in the form of energy, food, denuclarization, medical, and development (Manyin & Nikitin 2014).

For instance, as Manyin and Nikitin (2014, 11) report, "Four countries, China, South Korea, the United States, and Japan, have dominated the provision of food aid, contributing over 75% of the total since 1995, though only China has provided [food] assistance since 2009. In 2012, according to the World Food Programme (WFP), China provided nearly two-thirds of the 372,000 MT in food assistance provided to North Korea."